# Get xUnit Solution Directory Path

Tags: c#, .net, xunit

Does anyone have an idea of how I would be able to get and store(string) the path to my **solution directory** in an xUnit Project?

Comment: You almost cannot. The project/solution can be stored anywhere on the disk (even on different machines), and nothing in MSBuild system seem to provide the link. Why do you need that? There can be workarounds if you describe the real problem.

Comment: @LexLi Well, one case would be if you need access to sample files stored in source control (under the solution directory), but which are too big to be included as resources of the test assembly. I don't want MSBuild to copy 100 MB of files every time I compile the solution, and I need these files to run acceptance tests.

Comment: "I don't want MSBuild to copy 100 MB of files every time I compile the solution"? That won't happen if you use "copy if newer" https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/53248.visual-studio-copying-files-to-debug-or-release-folder.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Environment.CurrentDirectory works fine for what i need

Answer (score 2):

This works all the time

```
using System.IO;          // needed for Path
using System.Reflection;  // needed for Assembly

var path = new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase).LocalPath
var directoryPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(path)
```